# Some commands return no output in terminal even as root (remote machine)

Tags: command-line, output

First off - my linux knowledge is *very* limited. I only know what I can research online. I kinda like it that way, though, as the more I have to work to get the answer, the better the chance it'll stick for future use. (I've just hit a dead end on this one).

Secondly - all the following commands are run as root.

OS (on remote machine):

```
root@server:~# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial
```

Kernel:

```
root@server:~# uname -a
Linux server 2.6.32-042stab103.6 #1 SMP Wed Jan 21 13:07:39 MSK 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Below are a list of commands, where I get no output (possibly, there are more, but these are the ones I've found so far). I hit enter, and it simply goes to a new line with the cursor at a new prompt:

```
lsblk -o NAME,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL
fdisk -l
blkid
dpkg --list|grep linux-image
```

If I run the same commands with just the `--help` option, I get the help section without any issues on all four of them.

I thought maybe I'd somehow disabled echo, so I tried with `stty echo` and `stty sane` but it didn't change anything.

Any thoughts on what is wrong, what I am doing wrong, on how to solve it, or even ideas on where I can continue my search for an answer is very much appreciated - thank you for reading :)

Comment: You're on a VPS. It's possible you have no block devices and no kernel package installed, since both are on the host.

Comment: Very peculiar.  Try running `strace -o traceout.txt blkid ` for example, and use `less traceout.txt` . Check if there are `write()` calls. Also, have you executed something like `exec 1> somefile.txt` or anything involving `exec` command ?

Comment: @Serg: No write calls, and I haven't used the `exec` command. @muru: I _am_ on a VPS, yes. Doesn't the output of the uname return the installed kernel package that's currently running?

Comment: @Breagha `uname` tells you the kernel, yes, but I don't think it's in any way relevant to your issue. muru pointed out that you're on VPS, that can explain why commands related to block devices don't work, but that doesn't explain `dpkg -l` behavior.  Consider contacting whoever provides you the VPS, and asking whether they blocked certain commands.

Comment: @Serg - Thank you, I'll do that. And thank you to you both for the very quick replies :)

Comment: @Serg it explains the `dpkg` behaviour as well - no kernel package was ever installed on the container, so dpkg has no knowledge of any kernel packages. `apt` might. @Breagha: uname returns the name of the kernel currently running, which may or may not come from a package